# How to install and run Ramazes Rapaste easiest?

Tags: ruby, ramaze, rapaste

I'm pretty familiar with Ruby and Ramaze, but I wanted to provide my Admins with an install howto, since they're more familiar with Tomcat and standard Apache installations.

I tried it locally first and it got pretty long:

```
sudo aptitude install ruby1.8 ruby1.8-dev rubygems1.8 sqlite3

wget http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/archive/onig-5.8.0.tar.gz

tar zxvf onig-5.8.0.tar.gz

cd onig-5.8.0/

./configure

make

sudo make install

sudo gem install -r --include-dependencies --no-rdoc --no-ri ramaze mongrel sequel sqlite3-ruby ultraviolet

(mongrel 1.1.5 ruby)
(sqlite3-ruby 1.2.4 ruby)
(onigurama 1.1.0 ruby)

cp -r /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ramaze-2008.06/examples/app/rapaste .

cd rapaste/

vi start.rb
Change the following line (add "java" at position 0)
UV_PRIORITY_NAMES = %w[ java ruby plain_text html css javascript yaml diff ]

ruby start.rb --adapter mongrel --port 7000
```

Is there a shorter way? Where could I optimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those libraries and things are missing from the system, I don't see how this can be made much shorter.  The only further optimization might be to write a build script of some kind.